# Can I publish An Android App from two different accounts in separate countries?

Tags: android, software-distribution, app-distribution

I have a situation where I want to distribute An android app from two different accounts in two separate countries. Google provides a custom listing option, but I did not try that because I have only one Google Play Console account.
I want to make sure this is possible through a custom listing before paying for another account.

Comment: Hi! Is there a specific reason why you are trying to distribute the same app from two accounts? Are you aware that you can restrict the countries which can view your application from one account? https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7550024?hl=en

Comment: There is a tax-related issue in my local. I want to create two cash-flow streams one can be taxed locally, another revenue from the global operation, which I do not want to get taxed in the local country. I want to hand over global distribution to another company registered outside the country. Thank you for the link.

Comment: Gotcha. So it's the same app (same build, same version, same signature) but on two accounts, correct?

Comment: Yes, You understood correctly. Is it possible to use the custom listing offered by Google for this?